# @Html.DropDownList not showing selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to create one partial view to create drop down on every view. Have created one view model and partial view for the same. Its creating drop down properly but not showing selected value.

Below is View Model Class

```
public class drowDownVM
   {
       public string id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string cssClass { get; set; }
       public string keyColumnName { get; set; }
       public string valueColumnName { get; set; }
       public string selectedValue { get; set; }
       public string viewbagName { get; set; }
       public bool isMultipleSelect { get; set; }
       public List<int> multipleselectedValue { get; set; }
   }
```

Below is partial view to bind drop down

```
@if (Model != null)
{
   if (ViewData != null && ViewData.Count > 0 && ViewData.Keys.Contains(Model.viewbagName))
   {
       string ddName = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.name)) ? Model.name : "default-name";
       string viewBagName = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.viewbagName)) ? Model.viewbagName : ViewData.Keys.First();
       string keyColumnName = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.keyColumnName)) ? Model.keyColumnName : "id";
       string valueColumnName = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.valueColumnName)) ? Model.valueColumnName : "id";
       string selectedVal = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.selectedValue)) ? Model.selectedValue : "";
       List<int> multipleSelectVal = (Model.multipleselectedValue != null && Model.multipleselectedValue.Count > 0) ? Model.multipleselectedValue : new List<int>();
       var cssClass = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.cssClass)) ? Model.cssClass : "";
       if (!Model.isMultipleSelect)
       {
           <div>
               @Html.DropDownList(ddName, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[viewBagName], keyColumnName, valueColumnName, 2), "--Select--", new { @class = cssClass, @data_Val = selectedVal })
           </div>
       }
       else
       {
           @Html.ListBox(ddName, new MultiSelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[viewBagName], keyColumnName, valueColumnName, multipleSelectVal), new { @class = cssClass, @multiple = "multiple"})
       }
   }
}
else
{
   <p class="hidden">Model Data Not Found!</p>
}
```

Below is the code which calls partial view to bind drop down, first one is single select, second one is calling multiple select.

```
@Html.Partial("_dropdown", new drowDownVM() { cssClass = "form-control", id = "TargetTypeList", keyColumnName = "code_val", name = "TargetTypeList", selectedValue = "1", valueColumnName = "code_name", viewbagName = "TargetTypeList"})

@Html.Partial("_dropdown", new drowDownVM() { cssClass = "form-control", id = "TargetTypeList", isMultipleSelect = true, keyColumnName = "code_val", name = "TargetTypeList", selectedValue = "1", valueColumnName = "code_name", viewbagName = "TargetTypeList", multipleselectedValue = new List<int>() { 1, 2 } })
```

Comment: Note: If you want to create a resusable dropdown component only then no need to go for partial views you can try EditorTemplate in MVC

Comment: Dropdown list is not showing selected value . what it means ? you are not getting the selected value in the controller ? or when a user try to select a dropdown value in ui that time it is not at all selected ?? Please tell us the real issue. Question is little confusing

Comment: Suppose using this partial view in edit mode and want to show default selected value, at that time its not showing selected value.

Comment: SO you are getting dropdown values in UI but Default value is not selected right ?

Comment: What in the world are you trying do do here? Your code makes no sense and rhis is definitely not the way to generate form controls that bind to a model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I guess edit template and display template is way to go.

Comment: Also its better to use SelectListItem instead of getting details in viewdata and writing lot of logic with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList(ddName, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[@ViewBag.ViewBagName], keyColumnName, valueColumnName, 2), "--Select--", new { @class = cssClass, @data_Val = selectedVal })
</div>
```

Comment: This might answer the question, but without an explanation of what you've done and how it fixes the problem its not much use. Please expand on your answer and check the help centre - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - to see what is expected of a good answer.